# Join interval aggregated data in Bigquery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have one base table in bigquery having per minute data for whole day for different dates. I have created couple of other tables to calculate 15 min sum and daily sum. The sample tables are as below

```
user    age date            time            output
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:00:00    3
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:01:00    4
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:02:00    6
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:03:00    3
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:04:00    5
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:05:00    62
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:06:00    5
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:07:00    23
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:08:00    5
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:09:00    3
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:10:00    8
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:11:00    6
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:12:00    3
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:13:00    45
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:14:00    2
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:15:00    4
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:16:00    2
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:17:00    12
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:18:00    3
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:19:00    44
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:20:00    20
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:21:00    23
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:22:00    4
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:23:00    6
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:24:00    28
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:25:00    12
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:26:00    22
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:27:00    8
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:28:00    8
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:29:00    5
```

```
user    date            time_15min  15sum_output
abc 2023-02-15  11:00:00    183
abc 2023-02-15  11:15:00    201
```

```
user    date            dailysum_output 
abc 2023-02-15  384
```

I want to join the tables above to create the final table as below. All columns from first table and then aggregate columns based on date and time. Could you please suggest how can I achieve this in bigquery SQL

```
user    age date            time           output   15sum_output    dailysum_output
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:00:00    3   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:01:00    4   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:02:00    6   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:03:00    3   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:04:00    5   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:05:00    62  183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:06:00    5   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:07:00    23  183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:08:00    5   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:09:00    3   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:10:00    8   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:11:00    6   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:12:00    3   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:13:00    45  183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:14:00    2   183         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:15:00    4   201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:16:00    2   201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:17:00    12  201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:18:00    3   201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:19:00    44  201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:20:00    20  201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:21:00    23  201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:22:00    4   201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:23:00    6   201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:24:00    28  201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:25:00    12  201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:26:00    22  201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:27:00    8   201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:28:00    8   201         384
abc 24  2023-02-15  11:29:00    5   201         384
```

Tried left join with date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` the aggregate tables to the base table like below

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  -- put your sample table here
),
-- actual query starts here
`15min_slots` AS (
  SELECT user, date,
         DIV(TIME_DIFF(time, '0:0:0', SECOND), 15 * 60) time_slot,
         TIME_ADD(
           '0:0:0',
           INTERVAL DIV(TIME_DIFF(time, '0:0:0', SECOND), 15 * 60) * 15 MINUTE
         ) time_15min,
         SUM(output) `15sum_output`
    FROM sample_table
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
),
daily_sum AS (
  SELECT user, date, SUM(output) dailysum_output
    FROM sample_table
   GROUP BY 1, 2
)
SELECT t.*, s.`15sum_output`, ds.dailysum_output
  FROM sample_table t
  LEFT JOIN `15min_slots` s
    ON t.user = s.user AND t.date = s.date
   AND DIV(TIME_DIFF(t.time, '0:0:0', SECOND), 15 * 60) = s.time_slot
  LEFT JOIN daily_sum ds 
    ON t.user = ds.user AND t.date = ds.date
;

-- query result
+------+-----+------------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------------+
| user | age |    date    |   time   | output | 15sum_output | dailysum_output |
+------+-----+------------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------------+
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:00:00 |      3 |          183 |             384 |
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:01:00 |      4 |          183 |             384 |
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:02:00 |      6 |          183 |             384 |
 ~~~~~~~
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:13:00 |     45 |          183 |             384 |
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:14:00 |      2 |          183 |             384 |
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:15:00 |      4 |          201 |             384 |
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:16:00 |      2 |          201 |             384 |
~~~~~~~~
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:27:00 |      8 |          201 |             384 |
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:28:00 |      8 |          201 |             384 |
| abc  |  24 | 2023-02-15 | 11:29:00 |      5 |          201 |             384 |
+------+-----+------------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------------+
```

But, I would suggest to use a window function like below. It will return same result as above.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  -- put your sample table here
)
SELECT *,
       SUM(output) OVER w0 AS `15sum_output`, SUM(output) OVER w1 AS dailysum_output,
       SUM(output) OVER w2 AS hourly_output, SUM(output) OVER w3 AS weekly_output
  FROM sample_table
WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY user, date, DIV(TIME_DIFF(time, '0:0:0', SECOND), 15 * 60)),
       w1 AS (PARTITION BY user, date),
       w2 AS (PARTITION BY user, date, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time)),
       w3 AS (PARTITION BY user, EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date));
```

Comment: Awesome @Jaytiger, second query is much easier and work like magic in my environment. Thank you. One last thing if I want to add hourly and weekly sum as well in the same query, what would be my windows functions?

Comment: @Awssylearn, you can define additional window frames similar to`w0`.  I've updated the answer, so kindly check that out.

Comment: Perfect, working as expected except one error. I am using the function as below APPROX_QUANTILES(output,2)[OFFSET(1)] OVER w0 AS output_median..........I am getting an error as Syntax error: OVER keyword must follow a function call at [10:50]....directly running this quantiles function without window function is working fine.

Comment: `APPROX_QUANTILES` is not a window function, so can't go with a window frame definition.

Comment: oh okay, got it. All good then, code is working perfectly. Thank you for your help @Jaytiger